# Laravel forge, 403 when creating SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, forge

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel app on Forge. When I try to create an SSL certificate, I get this error:

```
2023-08-31 21:23:52 URL:https://forge-certificates.laravel.com/le/1892335/2086427
/ecdsa?env=production [4514] -> "letsencrypt_script1693517031" [1]
Cloning into 'letsencrypt1693517032'...
ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result: ["type"]  "http-01"
["status"]  "invalid"
["error","type"]    "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized"
["error","detail"]  "76.76.21.21: Invalid response from http://freddy.app/.well-known/acme-  
challenge/jyEqoCR9AgvVmuJvoz0cF-m0kqY-I4wRF6EvgHYNK2w: 404"
["error","status"]  403
["error"]   {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized","detail":"76.76.21.21: Invalid      
response from http://freddy.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/jyEqoCR9AgvVmuJvoz0cF-m0kqY-      
I4wRF6EvgHYNK2w: 404","status":403}
["url"] "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/260181948866/DBAvcQ"
["token"]   "jyEqoCR9AgvVmuJvoz0cF-m0kqY-I4wRF6EvgHYNK2w"
["validationRecord",0,"url"]    "http://freddy.app/.well-known/acme-challenge  
/jyEqoCR9AgvVmuJvoz0cF-    m0kqY-I4wRF6EvgHYNK2w"
["validationRecord",0,"hostname"]   "freddy.app"
["validationRecord",0,"port"]   "80"
["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved",0]    "76.76.21.21"
["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved"]  ["76.76.21.21"]
["validationRecord",0,"addressUsed"]    "76.76.21.21"
["validationRecord",0]  {"url":"http://freddy.app/.well-known/acme-challenge  
/jyEqoCR9AgvVmuJvoz0cF-m0kqY-
I4wRF6EvgHYNK2w","hostname":"freddy.app","port":"80","addressesResolved":
["76.76.21.21"],"addressUsed":"76.76.21.21"}
["validationRecord"]    [{"url":"http://freddy.app/.well-known/acme-challenge
/jyEqoCR9AgvVmuJvoz0cF-m0kqY-
I4wRF6EvgHYNK2w","hostname":"freddy.app","port":"80","addressesResolved":
["76.76.21.21"],"addressUsed":"76.76.21.21"}]
["validated"]   "2023-08-31T21:24:07Z")
```

I followed this tutorial to the letter https://buttercms.com/blog/laravel-forge/#tutorial-deploying-a-laravel-app-with-forge

As far as I have been able to gather it's an authorisation issue, but I don't have enough experience with Nginx (or deployment) to be able to figure it out. My Nginx file:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/freddy.app/before/*;

server {
listen 80 ssl;
listen [::]:80 ssl;
server_name freddy.app;
server_tokens off;
root /home/forge/freddy.app/public;

# return 301 https://freddy.app;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
# ssl_certificate
# ssl_certificate_key

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM- 
SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-
ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-
SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/freddy.app/server/*;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/freddy.app-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/freddy.app/after/*;
```

Any help would be appreciated.